# How to use the Trans component for bold or italicized text in the middle of a translation

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

This has been asked before, but I'm not able to comment on existing posts due to lacking reputation points so I am creating my own question.

I have a hard time understanding how to use the Trans component properly, as I find its documentation page to be a bit lacking and unclear.

I am trying to use nested bold or italicized text in my JSON strings. For context, I have translation file called "homepage.json" which I am keeping in my React app's public/locales/en/ subdirectory, using a format as follows:

```
{
"main": {
    "paragraph-text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit, <1>amet consectetur adipisicing elit</1>. Dolore ab modi autem veniam aperiam mollitia at assumenda sint repellat sunt quia recusandae laboriosam tempora, aliquam nemo in nostrum laudantium? Temporibus."
    }
}
```

My Trans component looks like this:

```
<Trans i18nKey={"homepage.main.paragraph-text"}>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, <em>amet consectetur adipisicing elit</em>. Dolore ab modi autem veniam aperiam mollitia at assumenda sint repellat sunt quia recusandae laboriosam tempora, aliquam nemo in nostrum laudantium? Temporibus.
</Trans>
```

When I try to create a French translation file for homepage.json, under public/locales/fr/ while using the exact same format as its English counterpart, when toggling between languages the library is not making use of the French text.

[This answer seems to describe exactly what I want to achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70666076/8072178), and I have attempted to implement the outlined solution into my application, but my Trans component instance does not appear to be able to locate the i18nkey value I pass to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. The problem is that I wasn't passing in the namespace of my translation file correctly to the Trans component.

As per my example above, the correct way to use Trans would be:

```
const { t } = useTranslation('myNamespace')
<Trans t={t} i18nKey={"main.paragraph-text"}>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, <em>amet consectetur adipisicing elit</em>. Dolore ab modi autem veniam aperiam mollitia at assumenda sint repellat sunt quia recusandae laboriosam tempora, aliquam nemo in nostrum laudantium? Temporibus.
</Trans>
```

Along with the correct usage in the JSON file:

```
{
"main": {
    "paragraph-text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit, <0>amet consectetur adipisicing elit</0>. Dolore ab modi autem veniam aperiam mollitia at assumenda sint repellat sunt quia recusandae laboriosam tempora, aliquam nemo in nostrum laudantium? Temporibus."
    }
}
```